# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') | Discord JS v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot that will automatically post a message once a document is added or modified in Firebase Firestore. I have run into an error, saying `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')` when trying to send a message to the channel.

How can I get the channel with the ID stored in `channelID`? I have tried the solution in the docs, but with no luck. The channel exists, so I don't understand why this error keeps coming.

Here is my code:

```js
const channelID = "1043109494625935387"
let botChannel

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  botChannel = client.channels.cache.fetch().find(channel => channel.id === channelID)
});

const doc = db.collection('announcements');

const observer = doc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
  docSnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
    if (doc.data().published === false) {
      await botChannel.send(doc.data().title)
    }
  })
}, err => {
  console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because everything inside `client.on('ready')` runs after you set `doc.onSnapshot`

When you set the `onSnapshot` listener, Firestore sends your listener an initial snapshot of the data (when `botChannel` is still `undefined`), and then another snapshot each time the document changes.

To solve this, you can move all this inside your callback. Also, you can fetch the channel instead.

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  const channelID = '1043109494625935387';
  const botChannel = await client.channels.fetch(channelID);

  db.collection('announcements').onSnapshot(
    (docSnapshot) => {
      docSnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        if (doc.data().published === false) {
          await botChannel.send(doc.data().title);
        }
      });
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
    },
  );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not recommended to fetch all channels at once. Instead, try fetching a single channel at once like so:

```
<client>.channels.fetch(SNOWFLAKE_ID)
```

Alternatively if you have the guild object, this will be faster

```
<guild>.channels.fetch(SNOWFLAKE_ID)
```

Do keep in mind that these methods both return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you might have to resolve it.

These solutions will work because the cache is not always up-to-date. If you want to get a channel it is highly recommended to just fetch it.